# Transferring JSON data to new page

Tags: jquery, json

I'm simply trying to get the contents of another page on my server using jquery, then displaying a part of the JSON data on another page. Heres what I have so far:

Page 1 data being taken from:

```
<script>
var namestest = {
"name1":"josh",
"id1":814922118,
"color1":"red"};
</script>
```

Page 2 trying to display the data on:

```
<div id="result"> </div>

<script>
$.get('http://sentinelgaming.org/test.php', function(data) {
    $("#result").html(namestest.name1);
});
</script>
```

Why would this not work?

Comment: Why would a declared variable on one site be available on another site, just because you retrieve the content from that other page as html? If JSON is what you want, store the file as JSON, not as HTML with a javascript variable (which you can't access).

Comment: yes thats right, then you can access them with the data variable like  data.name1

Answer (score 1):

Try

Page 1

```
{
"name1":"josh",
"id1":814922118,
"color1":"red"
}
```

Page 2

```
<script> $.get('http://sentinelgaming.org/test.php', function(data) {
    var namestest = eval('(' + data + ')' );
    $("#result").html(namestest.name1); }); </script>
```

Comment: This was an interesting try but I can't get it to work through any method because it's still not grabbing the content for some reason.

Comment: Are you able to print the JSON response in the callback function? Try $.ajax()

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure because the code doesn't seem correct to me. 
In the below code see the line
$("#result").html(namestest.name1);

it should be $("#result").html(data.name1) because you are passing response in the data variable.
    
        $.get('http://sentinelgaming.org/test.php', function(data) {
        $("#result").html(namestest.name1);
        });

Comment: That's what I thought too, but it wouldn't work because it can't grab the variable from the other page.

Comment: One more thing, in the response please set the content type "application/json".

Comment: I set it using resource.setContentType ("application/json"); and that didn't seem to affect it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem in your Json var the 2nd page not view it (you can make consloe.log(namestest)), so i think you need to define it as global variable